# Sequence number creation

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an ask to create numbers sequentially for list of tasks sent in a file.

1. Sequence Numbers should be assigned in order tasks are arranged
2. Tasks will be arriving to my application at different intervals. New tasks can be inserted in beginning , end or between existing tasks.
3. If a task was already assigned with a number, it should not be modified when a new task is added.
4. Sequence numbers can be integers or decimals with 1 precision.
   [image]

Is there any algorithm which solves this problem?

Comment: Why not always take the average of neighboring tasks when adding something between other tasks?

Comment: @Dave This number should be easily interpreted. If i take average, it will add more decimal precision and make it more complex. Also it need not to be a decimal number.

Comment: What do you mean by the "order tasks are arranged"? Didn't you say they could be shuffled?

Comment: @orSt What i mean by shuffled is, new tasks can be inserted between existing tasks in that file. How do i assign a number for such new tasks?

Comment: @Vel When are new tasks supposed to be inserted between/before existing ones?

Comment: Does it have to be a single number? Is 1.4.1.2.5 also a valid option as a task identifier?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It is preferred to be whole number or Decimal with 1 precision.

Comment: There's no solution without more info. I.e., no matter what sequence numbers we give the first 2 tasks, there are at most 10 * (S2-S1) valid sequence numbers between them. We'd need a cap on possible insertions between numbers or on the total number of tasks to come up with some reasonable heuristic.

Comment: @Dave we can safely assume total number of tasks would be <50.

Comment: @Vel I posted a solution that meets your requirements, but it's almost certainly overkill for what you need. What's the context? Maybe we can do better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have some guarantee on how unlucky you can be (how many times you'd have to insert a task in your smallest session id gap), you can't do better than averaging the neighbors every time. With big enough numbers and a cap of 50 tasks, this is compatible with integers.

```
Make fictional T endpoints with session IDs of 0 and 2^50 (# of tasks)
Each task gets the average of its neighbors' session ids.
T1 => S 2^49
T2 => S (0+2^49)/2 = 2^48 or (2^49+2^50)/2 = 2^49 + 2^48
etc...
```

All session id gaps are powers of 2, and we start with a big enough range that we can halve it 50 times if need be.

2^49 = 562,949,953,421,312; idk how much better this is than using a float

Comment: It depends on your definition of "number"; if it's a variable-length number (which can be encoded as a `byte[]`, `short[]`, etc., you can do better). But the OP isn't very clear on requirements unfortunately.